# Calculate the sum: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3+3n^2+2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I need to calculate this sum. what i tried is doing partial fraction decomposition.
so $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{A}{n} + \frac{B}{n+1} + \frac{C}{n+2}$$
and after calculating I got $$A = \frac{1}{2}$$ $$B = -\frac{1}{4}$$ $$C = \frac{1}{2}$$
and so the new series is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{4(n+1)} + \frac{1}{2(n+2)}\right)$$

Not sure how to calculate the sum from here. A solution would be appreciated!

Comment: you can decompose as: $\frac12(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1})-\frac12(\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2})$ and telescope.

Comment: By the way, your value for $B$ is wrong.

Comment: Also, your sum should probably start at $1$, the expression is undefined at $n=0$.

Comment: @KentaS currect about the sum I changed it to 1. Are you sure the value for B is wrong? I calculated it again and got the same value. Can you share your calculations? or the different value you got? thanks.

Comment: Use the decomposition suggested by@Kenta S to find the sum of the telescoping series. $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3+3n^2+2n}=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @EliBrown Just identifying the coefficient for $n^2$, you get $A+B+C=0$. You have $1/2+1/2-1/4=3/4$

Comment: The value for $B$ is $-1$

Comment: @ Eli Brown, plug $n=-1$ in $1=A(n+1)(n+2)+B(n(n+2))+C(n(n+1))$ to find $B=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your calculation. $B$ should be $-1$, then
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3+3n^2+2n}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{2(n+2)}\right)\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)\right]\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\cdots\right)\right]\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
   &=\frac{1}{4}.
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}